# laravel connect table with one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel php mysql. 
I have four tables

```
category   => id, name
site       => id, name, link
journalist => id, name
article    => title, body, journalist_id, site_id, category_id
```

I've defined `articles()` relationship in `Category`, `Journalist` and `Site` models.

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

When I insert data in article table how can I do that.

```
$site = Site::findOrFail(1);
$article = new Article(['title'=>'title', 'body'=>'body']);
$site->articles()->save($article);
```

and It inserts table that only connected to site table. 
I tried to following line and it saves row that doesn't connected to site, journalist, category table.

```
$article = new Article([
    'title'         => 'title',
    'body'          => 'body',
    'category_id'   => 1,
    'journalist_id' => 1,
    'site_id'       => 1
]);
$article->save();
```

I created table  that `$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();` and didn't write down the foreign ->references;

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kristina,

```
     $article = new Article(); 
     $article->title = $your_title 
     $article->name = $your_article_name;
     $article->site_id = $your_site_ID;
     $article->category_id = $your_category_ID;
     $article->journalist_id = $your_journalist_ID //or Auth::id() when authenticated user.
     $article->save();
```

Now you can use your articles method see complete guide [https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$site = Site::findOrFail(1);
$site->articles()->create(['title'=>'title', 'body'=>'body']); // use create() or insert()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define `articles` method in each Model (Category, Journalist and Site)

```
public function articles()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

then extract your appropriate record from the models and save them as you did with the site

```
$site = Site::findOrFail(1);
$category = Category::findOrFail(1);
$journalist = Journalist::findOrFail(1);

$article = new Article(['title' => 'title', 'body' => 'body']);

$site->articles()->save($article);
$category->articles()->save($article);
$journalist->articles()->save($article);
```

Comment: Is it ok that inserting one data  3 times?

Comment: the data at the end will be inserted only once with the category_id and journalist_id begin filled